# How to disable bounce effect of webcontainer in Windows 8 Mobile app

Tags: jquery, cordova, windows-phone-8, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a Hybrid app using cordova/phonegap.

There is a fixed header in the layout and it works good in android,IOS but in Windows 8 Phone [Lumia 920] when I scroll up the screen then the header also scrolls and sometimes it gets cutoff from the top and again after scrolling the screen down header comes to right place.

I am unable to find any fix, any help will be appreciated.

====Update 24/12/2013====

Found that this is called bounce effect.
I was able to fix that by using css :

```
touch-action:none;
```

but it also disabled all scroll and touch events of the device. So this didn't solved my problem. Still looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CordovaView.DisableBouncyScrolling = true;
        //Splash_Screen();
    }
```

Add the above lines to your main class c# file.

Use latest cordova 2.5+

Comment: Thanks, It is working but page scroll is affected, it is not scrolling smooth. Any idea ?

Comment: Thats Cordova framework level limitation. They are monitoring document height when it reaches bottom they are disabling mouse events. When you swipe in opposite direction cordova unlocks the scroll , so you can expect a jerk when you swipe for first time. Once unlocked scrolls smooth. But something is better than nothing. If answer has helped you accept it as correct answer.